# Phonegap cant lauch app

Tags: android, cordova

I've just created an app with `phonegap 3.4`, but can't launch app, I search it, but I can't find similar trouble. I guess that is something wrong with my emulator maybe. The following error comes below. Thanks.

```
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 5 seconds
WARNING : No target specified, deploying to emulator 'emulator-5554'.
Installing app on emulator...
Using apk: C:\Users\c1276197\Desktop\app\conversorBR\platforms\android\ant-build\HelloWorld-debug-un
aligned.apk

C:\Users\c1276197\Desktop\app\conversorBR\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Failed to launch app on emulator: Failed to install apk to emulator:    pkg: /data/local/tmp/HelloWo
rld-debug-unaligned.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the min-target-sdk version. I think that the 8 which you specify in the config.xml is being overwritten by Cordova/Phonegap CLI. What is the value of min-target-sdk when you look in the AndroidManifest.xml file of the app itself, after it is compiled? When I look at mine, it is always '10', which is Android 2.3.3. Since this is the min supported SDK, this is the reason adb is unable to install on your emulator. Bump your emulator SDK up to API 10 and it should work..

Cordova currently only supports Android 2.3 and above, see https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/commit/8d8cbf6e284bc67c4e8502a6238c83d2645b815e